# How to Retrieve User Properties with Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, api, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11

Hello I have the following code in a `Content Editor Web Part`, which retrieves the current user's name and displays it in a message box :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function getUser() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    //alert(userid);

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    }); 

    function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var loginName = data.d.Title;
        alert(loginName);
    } 
    function onError(error) {
        alert("Error on retrieving current user.");
    }
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        getUser();
    });
</script>
```

I was also able to display the email with `alert(data.d.Email);`.

However, when I try calling `data.d.Groups` (as per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246835.aspx) - which shows that a `Groups` property exists), I see a message box with `[object Object]`.

How can I retrieve the individual items from this (what I am assuming is a) collection?

I have tried :

```
var group = data.d.Groups[0];
alert(group);
```

But this just comes up with `undefined`.

Am I wrong in thinking that this object will contain my Department?

Either way, is there a way of iterating through these objects, or have I done it correctly but on an empty array?

Thank you

---

**Attempt at Logging the groups**

```
function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    console.log(loginName);

    var groups = data.d.Groups;
    console.log(groups);
}
```

I can't see either of the above logs in the `F12` console window... (Internet Explorer)

---

**Attempt 2 - Logging Successful**

Using the code below, I was able to achieve the same results as before, but this time the `console.log()` calls actually worked (still have no idea why the previous ones didn't):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var groups = currentUser.get_groups();
    alert(groups);
    console.log(groups);

    var name = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    alert(name);
    console.log(name);

    var id = currentUser.get_id();
    alert(name);

    var title = currentUser.get_title();
    alert(title);

    var email = currentUser.get_email();
    alert(email);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

After calling `console.log(groups);`, the following appeared in the F12 console :

[image]

Comment: Try logging `data.d.Groups` in console or create a fiddle if you can.

Comment: If you are not sure what you are receiving, I'd look at entire json response first to see where the information you want is located.

Comment: Also, you assumed that `groups` is an array by trying to access its index 0, but the docs says it is an object. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244862.aspx) Try what @Rohit416 suggested.

Comment: @jmugz3 Thanks both for your comments. I tried using `console.log(groups);`, but I can't see this in the `F12` console - is that the right place to check? I am relatively new to calling APIs in js so apologies if that is really obvious

Comment: `var group = data.d.groups`  <-- I think he was referring to that

Comment: @jmugz3 Apologies - yes that is what I meant: `var groups = data.d.Groups;    console.log(groups);`, which doesn't output anything to the F12 console s

Comment: Yes, `F12` is the key. It should work and log the statement. You need to write this in `success` function i.e. `console.log(data.d.Groups);`

Comment: Which browser you are using??

Comment: @Rohit416I am using Internet Explorer unfortunately, because I am (unfortunately) working with SharePoint!

Comment: Well, locate the console, in lower version like IE < 9 it is under script tab.

Comment: @Rohit416 I added the `console.log()`  code to my question, I think its right ...

Comment: Mention the IE version please!

Comment: @Rohit416 I'm on Version 11.0.9600.18314 (11), and I should also mention that this is being run from a Content Editor Web Part. My calls to `alert` all seem to work fine, but not `console.log`

Comment: @Rohit416 I was able to output the `Groups` object to the console, and I added an update to the question - If you get a chance could you please have a look and advise on what I need to do with this? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, you need to expand the objects inside to see which one has the data you need. After you figured out the correct object then the picture would be much more clear! So far it is difficult to tell by just looking at the image. If you could create a fiddle it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a rather ugly solution to this, but it does work.

First, we need to **call some .js files in preperation**:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>
```

Then, inside a `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">` tag, we declare some global variables and 2 main functions...

```
var currentUser;
var currentUserName;
var property = "Department";
```

**1. GetCurrentUserProperty(property)**:

This function actually only gets the current user for us and, if successful will call `loadUserData` (which actually gets the `property` we defined earlier for the given user:

```
// This function first gets the current user's firstname.lastname username (e.g. Joe.Bloggs).
// If this is successful, it calls the loadUserData function, which will retrieve the user's
// property which was defined in the global "property" variable.
function GetCurrentUserProperty(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQueryUserSuccess, onQueryUserFail);
}
function onQueryUserSuccess() {
    // If the query is successful, extract the first.last username and then call loadUserData
    window.currentUserName= currentUser.get_loginName().split("\\")[1]; 
    loadUserData(window.currentUserName);
}
function onQueryUserFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to retrieve user name');
}
```

**2. loadUserData**

This function takes the given user.name and will get the property that is stored in `property` for that user. Here, in the `success` function, I am just outputting the result to an `alert` window:

```
function loadUserData(userName){        
    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Property to fetch from the User Profile
    var strDepartment = window.property;

    //If you are on On-Premise:
    var targetUser = "BARDOM1\\" + userName;

    //Create new instance of UserProfileProperty
    departmentProperty = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(targetUser, strDepartment)

    //Execute the Query. (No load method necessary)
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}
function onSuccess() {    
    var messageText = window.property + " is " + departmentProperty .get_value();
    alert(messageText);
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}
```

Finally, to actually run this process, we need to call `GetCurrentUserProperty();`. I put all of this code into a file called `testproperty.js` and saved it in `SiteAssets`. Then, on the page where we want the code to run, add a `Content Editor Web Part` and in edit -> path the call is `../../SiteAssets/testproperty.js`. This will run  once the page load - hope this helps anyone else who may be stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

"data.d.Groups" is the Object, When you pass this into .html(data.d.Groups) you will get it as [object Object] only because object will convert as the string  Just loop the object and you will get the key and value

```
     for (key in data.d.Groups){
       alert("key: " + key + "value :" + data.d.Groups[key]);
     }
```